# I am trying to emulate a board which has a OLED display, but can't see anything. Can you tell me if there is something important I am not considering?

Tags: kernel, qemu, embedded, arm, emulation

I am just a newbie that is trying to learn. I can't see anything in the OLED display (ssd0303).
[image]

I am just using this demo: https://www.freertos.org/portlm3s811keil.html

as you can see it says that:

> The print task is the only task permitted to access the LCD - thus
> ensuring mutual exclusion and consistent access to the resource. Other
> tasks do not access the LCD directly, but instead send the text they
> wish to display to the print task. The print task spends most of its
> time blocked - only waking when a message is queued for display.

but actually, if I compile using `make` and running using `qemu-system-arm -M lm3s811evb -kernel gcc/RTOSDemo.bin` I can only see that black screen.

Why? Is there something I am not considering? It should work out of the box, since it's also writen in the official doc that I mentioned. So why I see black screen?

Probably there is something I am not considering because I am a newbie

Comment: Do not crosspost - `https://superuser.com/questions/1819794/i-am-trying-to-emulate-a-board-which-has-a-oled-display-but-cant-see-anything`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by compiling via Keil instead of gcc:
https://forums.freertos.org/t/i-am-trying-to-emulate-a-board-which-has-a-oled-display-but-cant-see-anything-can-you-tell-me-if-there-is-something-important-i-am-not-considering/18689/3